# What does the + operator do in CSS

Tags: css

Regarding the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisallenaaker/9BzsU/10/):

The radio buttons in the fiddle aren't acting the way radio buttons should.

I'm not familiar with + in CSS and I wonder if this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ ..... } 
 //a label that immediately follows an input of type radio that is checked
```

Answer (score 4):

The + sign in CSS denotes a selector that is adjacent to the first selector.

In your example the + sign is modifying the label not the actual radio button but the label only.

Now it is not working because you havent specified a group name (or name) for the radio button try the following html.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="rdo">
  <label for="radio1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="rdo">
  <label for="radio2"></label>
</form>
​
```

Now the radiobuttons are bound to the same name and will function correctly.

Cheers, Nico

Answer (score 3):

This selects the adjacent element, see [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

FTA:

> This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element. In this case, only the first paragraph after each ul will have red text.

Supported in IE7+

Comment: Haven't seen a more useful site than "The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize" since I first discovered StackOverflow. A big +1 !

Answer (score 2):

It matches a element immediately preceded another specified element.

In your example this would mean it matches any `label` element that follows an `input` element of `type="radio"`.

More information on selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the radio buttons not being mutually exclusive (you can select multiple ones), it is because the html does not define the radio buttons as being part of the same group.  Use the name attribute to make this happen.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radio1">
  <label for="radio1"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radio2">
  <label for="radio2"></label>
</form>
​
```

I believe your questions about the + in CSS is unrelated, but it is correctly identified as the next sibling in other answers.